# 2012 Mercedes will not start

Tags: starter

We parked the car over the weekend and it will not start back.  Dash lights and everything else did work, but now we have to disconnect the battery cables and reconnect to get that part working.  But it still will not start.  You can start it at the stared once you get the dash lights to come back on. What do we need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Find out if if you have a check engine light on or service light, if so i recommend taking it to your local parts store and have them check it with an OBD scanner and start from there or check all your fuses with a fuse light tester. There's usually a fuse box under the hood and one under the steering wheel behind a panel that will open.

If you have a battery that you can add water too, check it.. if its low add distilled water if you can afford some from walmart.

Distilled is highly recommended than regular waters because of the minerals, might want to jump it as well.

Also if you live in really cold arias, battiery's have harder time pushing out the correct CCA for your car/truck.

Let me know if all that dont work.